# Getting error while trying to connecting with the mysql work bench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am facing issue while connecting mysql server with mysql work bench I search for this issue and got some answers but that answers never work for me.

> The user specified as a definer ('mysql.infoschema'@'localhost') does
>   not exist

Comment: This is certainly because *"The user specified as a definer ('mysql.infoschema'@'localhost') does not exist"*

Comment: how can I solve it basically I am beginner on this can you help me in this regard??

Comment: Well, connect with a user that exists. Isn't the error message clear enough ?

Comment: I checked on lot of places every one just installing the mysql and trying to connect with work bench and they can do it easily with out doing any extra stuff